# Incorrect Elasticsearch statistic via Java client

Tags: java, elasticsearch, indexing, size

I am trying to get the index status for a very large index using the Java API. In the background, I am updating the same index with large amounts of data

I have tried

```
IndicesStatsResponse indicesStatsResponse = client.admin().indices()
            .prepareStats(index_name).all().execute().actionGet();
```

but this does not return the correct size because it is a very large index. However using the REST call, I got the correct answer.

```
GET /index_name/_stats
```

Perhaps I need to use some kind of listener mechanism, so I tried

```
IndicesStatsRequest req = new IndicesStatsRequest();
req.all();
client.admin().indices().stats(req, new ActionListener<IndicesStatsResponse>() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(IndicesStatsResponse response)
        {
            long s = response.getIndex(indexName).getTotal().getStore().getSizeInBytes();
            System.out.println(indexName + " " + s);        
        }
..       
});
```

but this threw `org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.EsRejectedExecutionException`

I also tried

```
IndicesStatsRequest req = new IndicesStatsRequest();
req.all();
ActionFuture<IndicesStatsResponse> statsResponseFeature = client.admin().indices().stats(req.clear().flush(true).refresh(true));
IndicesStatsResponse statsResponse = statsResponseFeature.get(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

But this did not retrieve any useful information.

Strangely enough, when I run it in debug mode in Eclipse, it works perfectly. So maybe there is some flush mechanism I am missing.
What is the way out?

Comment: what elasticsearch version is?

Comment: I am using 5.4.1, Really appreciate your help on this.